# Manually edit the bluetooth pairing list, phone keeps overwriting it with old list. How to stop that?

Tags: bluetooth, 4.3-jelly-bean, htc, samsung-galaxy-note-2, bluetooth-pairing

I have an Samsung Galaxy Note 2 and I wanted to connect my phone to an old HTC Rhyme docking station via bluetooth so I can use the speakers in it. I have all the data needed for the connection (ID, LinkKey, etc.) and I've edited the pairing list (path of it is in my case /data/misc/bluedroid/bt_config.xml). In that folder also was an bt_config.old file which was the same as the bt_config.xml file, I assume this is a backup file so I overwrote it as well after editing the list. This is how the part I added to the list looks like:

```
<N19 Tag="DC:DE:CA:0B:EF:C4">
        <N1 Tag="Timestamp" Type="int">1398527119</N1>
        <N2 Tag="Name" Type="string">HTC CR M540</N2>
        <N3 Tag="DevClass" Type="int">2360340</N3>
        <N4 Tag="DevType" Type="int">1</N4>
        <N5 Tag="AddrType" Type="int">0</N5>
        <N6 Tag="Manufacturer" Type="int">10</N6>
        <N7 Tag="LmpVer" Type="int">5</N7>
        <N8 Tag="LmpSubVer" Type="int">8953</N8>
        <N9 Tag="LinkKeyType" Type="int">4</N9>
        <N10 Tag="PinLength" Type="int">0</N10>
        <N11 Tag="LinkKey" Type="binary">a5c095e620e190f248f4b8a8b3291ed3</N11>
        <N12 Tag="Service" Type="string">0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb</N12>
        <N13 Tag="Aliase" type="string">htc dock test</N13>
    </N19>
```

When I overwrite the edited list with the original one everything looks fine until I restart my phone. After that somehow the old list gets loaded and I have no idea how that is possible. Either when I shut my phone down it saves the list that is already loaded or it has another directory for the pairing list which I need to edit as well.

Anyone have any idea how I could fix this overwriting problem? Obviously both the Note 2 and my old HTC Rhyme are rooted or else I could never get the bluetooth data. If more information is needed I can provide it.

Answer (score 1):

I did exactly the same thing successfuly by editing the bt_config.xml file in A HEX VIEWER in my PC and copying/replacing it using the Aoma Manager. My phone now connects automatically to the new device.